# how to run more than two cake php project run on one server

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I have to work on following step

#### local server

1. i have created new folder in webroot
2. put all cake php another project in side that folder
3. configure .htaccess in root folder ,app folder and webroot
4. then it is working fine

#### live server

1. i have to follow all the above step but it is not working on live server

Comment: You need to provide a lot more information for anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: Improved formatting

Comment: gives us more info. Do you mean running serval cakephp apps whith a single core ?